# How to write a correct handler with obtainMessage?

Tags: android, bluetooth, handler

There are no examples on how to write a handler using the `obtainMessage` method with 4 arguments coming in.

I've tried several ways, but still getting the same errors.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public final Message obtainMessage(int what, 
        int arg1, int arg2, Object obj) {

    }
};
```

This is obviously wrong, but I could use a little direction considering there aren't any examples to get help from.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](http://idlesun.blogspot.de/2012/12/android-handler-and-message-tutorial.html) these steps are required:

1. Create the `Handler` object exactly on the thread you want to handle
   messages.
2. Obtain a `Message` instance from the created `Handler` using `Handler.obtainMessage`. There is no need for this action to be performed on the `Handler`'s owner thread. It can be done from any other thread.
3. Send the message using `Handler.sendMessage`.

To further elaborate the process, here is a sample code in two sections. First is a sample `BluetoothThread` with minimal functionality to just send an imaginary file. The second section is a button click handler which uses the said thread.

```
public class BluetoothThread extends Thread {
    private Handler mHandler;

    public static final SEND_CODE = 1;
    public static final QUIT_CODE = 2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == SEND_CODE) {
                // Send the file using bluetooth
              }
            else if(msg.what == QUIT_CODE) {
              Looper.quitSafely();
            }
          }

        Looper.loop();
    }

    public Handler getThreadHandler() {
      return mHandler;
    }
}
```

And in the main activity:

```
public void ButtonClicked(View v) {
  BluetoothThread thread = new BluetoothThread();
  thread.Start();

  Handler hnd = thread.getThreadHandler();
  hnd.sendMessage(hnd.obtainMessage(BluetoothThread.SEND_CODE, 0, 0, null));
}
```

Comment: I just started working with the Handler class. I was thinking Handler.obtainMessage(...) obtained AND sent a message simultaneously, but this is not so. You must call sendMessage on the Message obtained from obtainMessage().